# How can I reuse software components across different devices in EA (Enterprise Architect)?

Tags: deployment, components, uml, modeling, enterprise-architect

Our system is composed of a lot of different device types. **Most of our software components are deployed on more than one device type**.

In terms of diagrams, how do I represent the fact that one software component C is deployed both on devices D1 and D2? If I create a deployment diagram with devices D1 and D2, then:

- Dragging C into D1 in the diagram will also move C into D1 in the Project Browser, and I want my software components not to be assigned to one device in particular
- I am not allowed to drag C into the diagram more than once. How can I represent in the same diagram the fact that C is deployed both on D1 and D2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do that by creating instances. You have a package with components that represent a blueprint (like `Acre PC X4711` which represents a general type). Now you Ctrl-drag that onto your deployment diagram for a certain location. Choose "As Instance" from the appearing pop up and eventually name the device (e.g. "John's PC"). Additionally you can assign tagged values for the serial number etc. It might be a good idea to create a MDG to assist you with that.